# Weed classification using CNN for Hyper-spectral images

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, gis, conv-neural-network

The problem I am working on is Weed classification.
I have a hyper-spectral data of wavelength range 400-1000nm. There are 61 bands and the size of data file is 1320 x 1040 x 61. So is it correct to generate the images like that for the convolutional neural network.

Matlab code:

```
for cnt1=1:61
    for cnt2=1:61
        for cnt3=1:61
            slice1(:,:,1) = output(:,:,cnt);
            slice1(:,:,2) = output(:,:,cnt2);
            slice1(:,:,3) = output(:,:,cnt3);
             imwrite ((slice1),strcat('C:\Users\Desktop\Plant\image_',num2str(cnt1),'_',num2str(cnt2),'_',num2str(cnt3),'.png'));
        end
    end
end
```

From this combination of 3 bands I can generate 61*61*61= 226981. From that I can choose the images which have some clear visualisation of weeds for the classification using CNN.

Is this process is correct?

Comment: sorry what that means?